# Having trouble with a beginner python program that I tried - why is this not working?

Tags: python-2.7

I get an error on the final else of the code, but knowing me there's probably something else wrong with it besides that. I'd appreciate any help I can get. Thanks :)

```
carryon = True
while carryon == True:
   side1 = int(input("Please enter the smallest side of the triangle."))
   side2 = int(input("Please enter the second smallest side of the triangle."))
   side3 = int(input("Please enter the hypotenuse of the triangle."))
   if (side1 ** 2) + (side2 ** 2) == (side3 ** 2):
        print "Your triangle is a triple!"
    user = input("Would you like to continue? Type y to continue entering side lengths, type n to stop.")
    user.lower()
     if user == 'y':
      continue
     elif user == 'n':
      carryon = False
     else: 
      print "Please type either y or n!"
  else: 
    print "Your triangle is not a triple!"
```

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving?

Comment: @Dave2e it says invalid syntax for the final else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you had a couple of mistakes.  A logic error on where the second else was located, potential an indentation error and for my Python 2.7.  Also Python was having issues converting the value from input into a string, I had better luck with input_raw() for entering a string value.

```
carryon = True
while carryon == True:
    side1 = int(input("Please enter the smallest side of the triangle."))
    side2 = int(input("Please enter the second smallest side of the triangle."))
    side3 = int(input("Please enter the hypotenuse of the triangle."))
    if (side1 ** 2) + (side2 ** 2) == (side3 ** 2):
          print "Your triangle is a triple!"
    else: 
         print "Your triangle is not a triple!"

    user = raw_input("Would you like to continue? Type y to continue entering side lengths, type n to stop.")
    user.lower()
    if user == "y":
        continue
    elif user == 'n':
        carryon = False
    else: 
        print "Please type either y or n!"
```